# Assigning a role to a specific custom post type (and ignoring other post types)

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, customization, users

I have a new post type called "story"

And a new role called 'Writer' (w/ a 'publish_story' capability)

I want it so that, a Writer when logged in can edit Profile and only edit a custom post type - "story"

However, by adding the 'publish_posts' capability, it allows Writer to also manage other custom post types including the main 'Posts' as well. I just want to restrict user of a certain role/capability to manage certain custom post type only.

This is part of a simple plugin I'm writing to distribute, so I don't want to integrate with other plugins to make it simple, nor tell my users to edit the function.php or users.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [create a new role](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role) and [add specific capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap).

Or you can conditionally [remove access to Edit Posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page) and any other admin menu items.